# creating new string with alternating elements in python

Tags: python

I need to make a new list that contains alternating  elements from the two list from before.
example: listA = "a","b","c"
         listB= "A","B","C"
the output should be "a","A","b","B","c","C"

```
def one_each(lst1,lst2):
        newList=[]
        for i in range(len(lst2)):
              newList.append(lst1[i])
              newList.append(lst2[i])
        return newList
```

Comment: `it.chain.from_iterable(zip(a,b))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use small length list to reiterate so, add `if condition` to get your length
try this one:

```
def one_each(lst1,lst2):
  iRange=len(lst1)
  if len(lst2)<iRange:
    iRange=len(lst2)
  newList=[]
  for i in range(iRange):
        newList.append(lst1[i])
        newList.append(lst2[i])
  return newList

print (['a','b','c'],['A','B','C','D'])
```

output:

```
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'c']
```

Comment: The lists are different sizes

Comment: then use small size list to iterate

Comment: BTW if `A` has 3 element and `B` has 5 then last 2 element of new list must be non alternative is it like that ?

Comment: once A is done and its finished alternating, the extras for B shouldnt show

Comment: can you please update your question and add your error pron code on post or your tested sample data

Comment: so we can easily help to fix it

Comment: i changed it  now

Answer (score 0):

Try using a single loop over the index range of one of the two lists, then append an element from each list at each iteration.

```
def one_each(lst1, lst2):
    lst = []
    for i in range(0, len(lst1)):
        lst.append(lst1[i])
        lst.append(lst2[i])
    return lst

lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lst2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']

output = one_each(lst1, lst2)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I've used zip and concate all the elements.

```
listA = ["a","b","c"]
listB= ["A","B","C"]
print reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,zip(listA, listB))

Result: ('a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C')
```